# Clion: auto documenting functions, classes

Tags: c++, c, ide, documentation, clion

Is there any shortcut or something like this to add, e.g. documentation of a function or class (similar to `"///"` in Visual Studio and C#)?

Thanks!

Comment: It's gonna be /** resume @param bar @ return foo */ doxygen style but the autocreation is not implemented yet, but the documentation works

Answer (score 15):

You can use `/** <Enter>`.
I have found a way to do it. I personally use Doxygen for documentation.
[CLion plans to integrate it](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/04/clion-1-1-roadmap-accu-2015/#comment-8391).
You have to write all of it at this time. But when you have documented your code, you can build it with CMake (and then it appears in your build target on CLion).

Here's an example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(doxygen_test)

find_package(Doxygen)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cc)

if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)

  set(DOXYGEN_INPUT ${SOURCE_FILES})
  set(DOXYGEN_OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile)

  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${DOXYGEN_OUTPUT}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append "Building API Documentation..."
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_INPUT}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Done."
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    DEPENDS ${DOXYGEN_INPUT}
  )

  add_custom_target(apidoc ALL DEPENDS ${DOXYGEN_OUTPUT})

  add_custom_target(apidoc_forced
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append "Building API Documentation..."
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_INPUT}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Done."
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  )

endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")


add_executable(doxygen_test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Sources:

1. http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-February/012796.html
2. https://www.tty1.net/blog/2014/cmake-doxygen_en.html
3. https://mementocodex.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/how-to-generate-code-documentation-with-doxygen-and-cmake-a-slightly-improved-approach/
4. https://majewsky.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/tip-of-the-day-cmake-and-doxygen/

Answer (score 8):

Starting from 2016.2 EAP CLion supports Doxygen (http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/05/keep-your-code-documented/). Start with typing “/**” or “/*!” and then press Enter. In case your function has parameters, returns a value or throws an exception, you’ll get a stub to fill with the documentation text

Comment: Starting with `///` works as well, I just tried it. 

Also, the style of the auto-generated documentation can be customised from Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Documentation comments (on a Mac). E.g, you can choose between `\param` and `@param`.